# SQL Combine Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue where my SQL query will not get rid of null values.

I have tried a myriad of different techniques, but I am a novice.

My desired result is an Order number followed by the date which the status occurs all in one line.

```
select mo.order_id OrderID,
case when osr.order_status_cd = 120 and osr.create_date is not null then    osr.create_date end as POCreated,
case when osr.order_status_cd = 220 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end as Ordered,
case when osr.order_status_cd = 300 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end as Shipped,
case when osr.order_status_cd = 400 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end as Received,
case when osr.order_status_cd = 500 and osr.create_date is not null then    osr.create_date end as Completed,
from order_status_record osr
inner join msorder mo on mo.order_id = osr.msorder_id
```

Instead of getting results that look like this:

```
OrderID POCreated   Ordered     Shipped      Received    Completed
497822  11/18/2012  NULL          NULL        NULL        NULL
497822  NULL       11/19/2012     NULL        NULL        NULL
497822  NULL        NULL       11/19/2012     NULL        NULL
497822  NULL        NULL          NULL     11/19/2012     NULL
497822  NULL        NULL          NULL        NULL     11/19/2012
```

I want this:

```
OrderID POCreated   Ordered     Shipped      Received    Completed
497822  11/18/2012  11/19/2012  11/19/2012   11/19/2012  11/19/2012
```

Do I need to create a virtual table? Do I need an if function? Why do the Nulls still populate?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: By the way, all the `and osr.create_date is not null` bits in your CASEs are superfluous and can be left out. Any of these CASEs evaluates to NULL if its condition isn't satisfied. So presently, when `osr.create_date` is NULL but the first part of the condition is true, your CASE returns NULL because the entire condition is false. However, the modified CASE (with the shortened condition) would return NULL as well, only it would return it as the contents of `osr.create_date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add an aggregate function to each of the `CASE` statements and then a `GROUP BY` the records will consolidate into a single row:

```
select mo.order_id OrderID,
  max(case when osr.order_status_cd = 120 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end) as POCreated,
  max(case when osr.order_status_cd = 220 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end) as Ordered,
  max(case when osr.order_status_cd = 300 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end) as Shipped,
  max(case when osr.order_status_cd = 400 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end) as Received,
  max(case when osr.order_status_cd = 500 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end) as Completed,
from order_status_record osr
inner join msorder mo 
  on mo.order_id = osr.msorder_id
group by mo.order_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` to group the order IDs into a row, and `MAX` on the case statements to get the right row:

```
select mo.order_id OrderID,
    MAX(case when osr.order_status_cd = 120 and osr.create_date is not null then    osr.create_date end) as POCreated,
    MAX(case when osr.order_status_cd = 220 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end) as Ordered,
    MAX(case when osr.order_status_cd = 300 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end) as Shipped,
    MAX(case when osr.order_status_cd = 400 and osr.create_date is not null then osr.create_date end) as Received,
    MAX(case when osr.order_status_cd = 500 and osr.create_date is not null then    osr.create_date end) as Completed,
from order_status_record osr
inner join msorder mo on mo.order_id = osr.msorder_id
GROUP BY order_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had other fields to add so I put them in the group by clause and I was good to go.

Comment: This will not work as written because you cannot use a column alias in a `GROUP BY` clause, you would need to reference the actual column name `mo.order_id`

Comment: I did. I used mo.order_id along with the other applicable columns. I understand that column aliases are not useable object in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `(msorder_id, order_status_cd)` is `UNIQUE` in table `order_status_record`, here is a solution without `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    mo.order_id         AS OrderID,
    osr120.create_date  AS POCreated,
    osr220.create_date  AS Ordered,
    osr300.create_date  AS Shipped,
    osr400.create_date  AS Received,
    osr500.create_date  AS Completed
FROM 
    msorder AS mo 
  LEFT JOIN 
    order_status_record AS osr120 
      ON  osr120.msorder_id = mo.order_id 
      AND osr120.order_status_cd = 120 
  LEFT JOIN 
    order_status_record AS osr220 
      ON  osr220.msorder_id = mo.order_id 
      AND osr220.order_status_cd = 220 
  LEFT JOIN 
    order_status_record AS osr300 
      ON  osr300.msorder_id = mo.order_id 
      AND osr300.order_status_cd = 300 
  LEFT JOIN 
    order_status_record AS osr400 
      ON  osr400.msorder_id = mo.order_id 
      AND osr400.order_status_cd = 400 
  LEFT JOIN 
    order_status_record AS osr500 
      ON  osr500.msorder_id = mo.order_id 
      AND osr500.order_status_cd = 500 ;
```

Comment: I am actually using select distinct. Is there an advantage to doing it this way?

Comment: Why do you need the `DISTINCT` for?

Comment: There will be duplicate records due to a large amount of extra data.

Comment: If the combination I mentioned, `(msorder_id, order_status_cd)` is not unique, then the query by bluefeet and dbaseman will be more efficient. Can you test what this returns?: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM order_status_record GROUP BY msorder_id, order_status_cd HAVING COUNT(*)>1) tmp ;`

Comment: To simplify the question I took out other fields I did not need. Some of these are multiple product numbers or Purchase orders. I added these to the group by and used select distinct. When I try the query you gave me to test it says: No column name was specified for column 1 of 'tmp'. I am very green in SQL.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My query has no `GROUP BY`. If the columns you need are from table `msorder`, you can add them without `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`.

Comment: retry: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT msorder_id FROM order_status_record GROUP BY msorder_id, order_status_cd HAVING COUNT(*)>1) tmp ;`

Comment: No I understand, I used the query by bluefeet and dbaseman and got the desired results. I just am curious what advantages there are to your suggestion.

Comment: I used the new count and the results were 37,672. I am joining 9 different tables.